# Refactoring advice for parser and calculator for logical expressions

Tags: c#, parsing, calculator

I have a code for parser and calculator of logical expressions. And I don't quite like how it looks.

For the background.

It supports following operations for operands

bool: **OR, And , Not**

int: **More than, less than**

both bool and int: **Equals**

I've created general interface `IElement` for describing any element of expression. There are also other interfaces:

1. `IBinary : IOperation`
2. `IValue : IElement`
3. `IOperation : IElement`
4. `IVariable<T> : IElement, IValue`
5. `IBinaryOperation<T> : IOperation, IBinary`
6. `IUnaryOperation : IOperation`

And those interfaces interfaces has following classes as implementations

1. `Variable<T> : IVariable<T>`
2. `Not : IUnaryOperation`
3. `And : IBinaryOperation<bool>`
4. `Or : IBinaryOperation<bool>`
5. `LessThen : IBinaryOperation<int>`
6. `GreaterThen : IBinaryOperation<int>`
7. `Eq : IBinaryOperation<int>, IBinaryOperation<bool>`

Units of the expression is represented as `List<Element>` in postfix notation .
Here's my `Compute` method and couple methods used inside of it. I have a problem with both of inner methods.

```c
public static bool Compute(List<IElement> element)
            {
                Stack<IElement> stack = new Stack<IElement>();
                foreach (IElement elem in element)
                {
                    IElement tmp = elem;
                    switch (elem)
                    {
                        case IValue val:
                            {
                                stack.Push(val);
                                break;
                            }
                        case IBinary val:
                            {
                                HandleBinary(val, ref stack);
                                break;
                            }
                        case IUnaryOperation val:
                            {
                                HandleUnary(val, ref stack);
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                return ((IVariable<bool>)stack.Pop()).getValue();
            }
```

```c
    private static void HandleBinary(IElement elem, ref Stack<IElement> stack)
                {
    
                    switch (elem)
                    {
                        case And and:
                            {
                                Tuple<IVariable<bool>, IVariable<bool>> operands = GetBoolOperands(ref stack);
                                stack.Push(and.Execute(operands.Item2, operands.Item1));
                                break;
                            }
                        case Or or:
                            {
                                Tuple<IVariable<bool>, IVariable<bool>> operands = GetBoolOperands(ref stack);
                                stack.Push(or.Execute(operands.Item2, operands.Item1));
                                break;
                            }
                        case Eq eq:
                            {
                                Type t = stack.Peek().GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
                                switch (Type.GetTypeCode(t))
                                {
                                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                                        {
                                            Tuple<IVariable<int>, IVariable<int>> operands = GetIntOperands(ref stack);
                                            stack.Push(eq.Execute(operands.Item2, operands.Item1));
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    case TypeCode.Boolean:
                                        {
                                            Tuple<IVariable<bool>, IVariable<bool>> operands = GetBoolOperands(ref stack);
                                            stack.Push(eq.Execute(operands.Item2, operands.Item1));
                                            break;
                                        }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        case GreaterThan gt:
                            {
                                Tuple<IVariable<int>, IVariable<int>> operands = GetIntOperands(ref stack);
                                stack.Push(gt.Execute(operands.Item2, operands.Item1));
                                break;
                            }
                        case LowerThan lt:
                            {
                                Tuple<IVariable<int>, IVariable<int>> operands = GetIntOperands(ref stack);
                                stack.Push(lt.Execute(operands.Item2, operands.Item1));
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
```

```c
             private static Tuple<IVariable<int>, IVariable<int>> GetIntOperands(ref Stack<IElement> stack)
            {
                return new Tuple<IVariable<int>, IVariable<int>>(
                    (IVariable<int>)stack.Pop(),
                    (IVariable<int>)stack.Pop());

            }
            private static Tuple<IVariable<bool>, IVariable<bool>> GetBoolOperands(ref Stack<IElement> stack)
            {
                return new Tuple<IVariable<bool>, IVariable<bool>>(
                    (IVariable<bool>)stack.Pop(),
                    (IVariable<bool>)stack.Pop());

            }
```

As you can see this code has a lot of pattern matching and type casting, thit is expensive and that amount of casts worries.

I feel like my attempt to utilize polymorphism is failed and whole preparation with those interfaces and implementations is wasted.

I've tried to refactor this code but always ran into the problem of high amount of type casting and pattern matching.

Can someone suggest another approach or point out an obvious but missed error.

Comment: Have you considered using an [AST](https://www.google.com/search?q=Abstract+Syntax+Tree)?

Comment: Wow, thanks that looks promising

Comment: Regarding performance: do you want the execution be fast or the building of the expression? If you will reuse the same expressions very often, maybe it would make sense to have a look on the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace. However, at "compile time", the amount of pattern matching will be the same.

Comment: Search on "Parser and AST generators". Knowing when and how to use those tools is probably more valuable than knowing how to write parsers and design AST's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of all the switch case statement, maybe it would be helpful to actually use polymorphism. For my examples, I would dicard the interfaces and use the classes only.

I would suggest that you add some methods to your classes. One could be called `virtual void Evaluate(stack);`. The switch-case simplifies now to a single virtual method call:

```
Stack<Element> stack = new Stack<Element>();
foreach (Element elem in element)
{
    elem.Evaluate(stack);
}
```

The individual cases have to be implemented in the in the corresponding classes (Variable, And, Or, ...):

```
abstract class Element
{
    public abstract void Evaluate(Stack<Element> stack);
}

class Variable<T> : Element, IComparable where T : IComparable
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    
    public override void Evaluate(Stack<Element> stack)
    {
        stack.Push(this);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Variable<T> var && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Value, var.Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Variable<T> var)
            return Value.CompareTo(var.Value);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

abstract class Binary : Element {}

class And : Binary
{
    public override void Evaluate(Stack<Element> stack)
    {
        var op1 = (Variable<bool>)stack.Pop();
        var op2 = (Variable<bool>)stack.Pop();
        stack.Push(new Variable<bool>() { Value = op1.Value && op2.Value });
    }
}

class Eq : Binary
{
    public override void Evaluate(Stack<Element> stack)
    {
        var op1 = stack.Pop();
        var op2 = stack.Pop();
        stack.Push(new Variable<bool>() { Value = op1.Equals(op2) });
    }
}

class GreaterThan : Binary
{
    public override void Evaluate(Stack<Element> stack)
    {
        var op1 = (IComparable)stack.Pop();
        var op2 = (IComparable)stack.Pop();
        stack.Push(new Variable<bool>() { Value = op1.CompareTo(op2) > 0 });
    }
}
```

For the `Eq` case, I have overridden the default Equals method (one should in this case also override the GetHashCode method, although it is not necessary here). For the `GreaterThan`/`LessThan` cases, I have implemented the `IComparable` interface to `Variable<T>`.